# Looking for an Argument Mining dataset of customer reviews

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I am looking for a dataset containing customer reviews (can be about hotels, restaurants, movies...) to build an algorithm able to detect arguments (premises, evidences...) in a given review and the relation between them.

My research leads me to [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332702231_A_Hotel_Review_Corpus_for_Argument_Mining) hotel reviews dataset.

However, it does not seem available for download.

Is there any public customer reviews dataset for argument detection or anything close?

Answer (score 1):

[Customer Support on Twitter](https://www.kaggle.com/thoughtvector/customer-support-on-twitter): This Kaggle dataset includes more than 3 million tweets and responses from leading brands on Twitter.

[Relational Strategies in Customer Service Dataset](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nextit-public/cl2017data.html): A dataset of travel-related customer service data from four sources. Conversation logs from three commercial customer service VIAs and airline forums on TripAdvisor.com during the month of August 2016.

[Ubuntu Dialogue Corpus](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/ubuntu-dialogue-corpus): Consists of nearly one million two-person conversations from Ubuntu discussion logs, used to receive technical support for various Ubuntu-related issues. The dataset contains 930,000 dialogs and over 100,000,000 words.